# Jquery background image fade - Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, background

I am pretty new to js and jquery so I've written something that basically does what I want it to do, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it. It's also a bit buggy so I'm hoping that can be fixed.

My website is here http://www.madebyandrew.com and I wish to discuss the menu, which appears as an overlay when you click 'menu' at the top.

Basically what I have done is create a ul list in the html which looks like this

```
<ul id="menuList">

    <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">NZSki</a></li><br/>
    <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Theta</a></li> <br/>
    <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Ports of Auckland</a></li> <br/>
    <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Total Compliance</a></li> <br/>
    <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Ted's Grooming Room</a></li> <br/>
    <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Coffee & Jam</a></li> <br/>
    <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Treble Seven</a></li> <br/>
    <li class="bgButton"><a href="#">Diacle</a></li> <br/>

</ul>
```

When you hover over a link I want a relevant image to be shown full screen in the background. To do this, I have created a div classed bgimage, which has the following css attributes:

```
.bgimage{

  position:fixed;
  z-index:-10;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center !important; 

}
```

I have created an array to store my different background images, and I created a variable which takes the index of the highlighted li and uses this to get the correct background from the array. I then used .hover to fade the background image in and out when the mouse hovers over one of the links.

```
var bgImg = ["url('images/menu1/background1.jpg')",
"url('images/menu1/background2.jpg')",
"url('images/menu1/background3.jpg')",
"url('images/menu1/background4.jpg')",
"url('images/menu1/background5.jpg')",
"url('images/menu1/background6.jpg')",
"url('images/menu1/background7.jpg')",
"url('images/menu1/background8.jpg')"];


$(".bgButton").hover(
  function () {
   var index = $( "li" ).index(this);
    $(".bgimage").css({
      display: "none",
      background: bgImg[index]
    });
  $(".bgimage").fadeIn(400);
 }, function() {
  $(".bgimage").fadeOut(200);
 }
);
```

So, this now does roughly what I want it to. Except, it seems to be buggy. When I hover over a link and remove the mouse quickly, the background image sometimes flashes. Plus if I hover over the link and remove the mouse quickly, the fadeIn animation has to complete fully before the fadeOut one can begin, meaning it doesn't feel like it's being responsive. There's also the problem when you move from one link to another quickly, I'd like for one to fade out while the other fades in. However, it can't do this because I change the background image immediately.

I'd be grateful if anyone can point me to a better way of doing this as my knowledge just isn't up to scratch.

Thanks!

***EDIT***

As suggested by Mitko below, I have added

```
$(".bgimage").stop()
```

This has stopped the animation from playing over and over, so it's getting closer. However when you hop from one link to the next quickly, there is no fade animation.

What I'd like it to do when you jump from one link to another, is to complete the fadeout animation first, then fade in with the current one, if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will transition more nicely if you use the css transition property. Transition doesn't work on the background-image property, but if you stack the images on top of each other you can transition their opacities.

Example:

```
<div class="menu-background">
    <div class="bg-0 bgimage"></div>
    <div class="bg-1 bgimage"></div>
    <div class="bg-2 bgimage"></div>
</div>
```

Then update your css:

```
.bgimage {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.bgimage.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.bg-0 {
    background-image: url('images/menu1/background1.jpg');
}
...
```

And in your javascript,

```
$(".bgButton").hover(
  function () {
    var index = $( "li" ).index(this);
    $(".bg-" + index).addClass('active');
  }, function() {
    $(".bgimage").removeClass('active');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems that you mentioned are because the animations (fadeIn and fadeOut), haven't finished, when another animations are started. To stop the running animations call `$(".bgimage").stop()`, before calling fadeIn and fadeOut.